# How Debug File System Minifilter Driver on WDK 7.1

Tags: c++, driver, wdk, filter-driver

I download WDK 7.1 [because WDK8.1 Update not downloaded and stay 0% on instillation].
**I wanna debug [File System Minifilter Driver](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Minispy-File-System-97844844) with WDK 7.1** - but when i debug on Win7 Debug i have an error.

---

**Error:**

```
error MSB8020:  The build tools for WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 build tools, please install WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...". C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   64  5   minispy (User\minispy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `WDK8.1` for that, MS samples aren't compatible with older `WDK` releases. This sample requires `VS2013` (as stated in the referenced page) and `VS2013` is coupled with `WDK8.1`.